# ASP.NET MVC : How to create own HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

My idea was to create my own HttpContext which will include some of the internal objects used in our app. So I thought I will simply create

```
public class FooHttpContextBase : HttpContextBase
{
    public string Foo
    {
        get { return "Boo"; }
    }
}
```

And then override HttpContext property:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    private FooHttpContextBase context;

    public BaseController()
    {
        context = new FooHttpContextBase();
    }

    override public HttpContextBase HttpContext
    {
        get { return context; }
    }
}
```

But then I've realized HttpContext is not a virtual - so it cannot be overridden.

Well, what do you suggest? Add some new property into the BaseController?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even if you could inject your own `HttpContext` descendant, what good would that do?  What do you intend to put in it?

Comment: Are you trying to implement global settings for all sessions or session specific settings?

Comment: It depends *entirely* on exactly what you're storing, and you haven't told us anything about that. There are lots of places to squirrel data away. Which one is right depends upon how the data is to be used.

Comment: I'd like to store some session specific objects. First which come into my mind is Account object used in our app. Or some other 'session specific' objects.

Comment: Session and membership are almost completely unrelated. Security-sensitive information should always be in a principal rather than session. Session is *insecure.* So again, you need to be precise about what you're storing.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I recommend you just add a new property to your base controller that will share your own context. It's the most easy, elegant and fast way to do the job.
If you are using some IOC, I recommend you to do a property injection for it, see [this link](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/11/constructor-injection-vs-sette-injection/) for details.

Comment: Yes, if this is the best way how to do that then it's ok for me.

Comment: -1 There is no need to be crass. If you have an answer to the question, simply state the solution.